# Marklogic : Pagination in search:search based on eleemnt node instead of document uri

Tags: marklogic

I have following `xml` format in **wells.xml**

```
<wells><well><date-created>MMDDYYYY</date-created><title>ABC</title></well><well><date-created>MMDDYYYY</date-created><title>ABC</title></well></wells>
```

Now I performed following search query :

```
declare namespace ts= "http://marklogic.com/mlu/clover/docs-xml";
import module namespace search ="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
declare variable $options :=<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"><transform-results apply="snippet"></transform-results></options>;
for $doc in search:search("ABC",$options,1,1)//search:match 
return $doc
```

In result it is giving me two results set as both record in a same document wherever I passed (1,1) combination in `search:search`.

Please help how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The search library, as well as all of MarkLogic's indexes are fragment/document based. So, perhaps best to split the wells document into individual well documents. But you can also easily achieve what you are looking for by adding a searchable expression. Add the following to your search options:

```
<searchable-expression>//well</searchable-expression>
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for quick response i understand that splitting that wells document into multiple well documents is one of the solution but i cant do this, also tried your solution : <search-expression> but still getting two results where i passed (1,1) combination.

Comment: @user1660340 I checked before posting, it should work. I stored your XML as is, ran the search, got 2 matches with one result. With the searchable expression, I still get one result, but with only one match. The matches should be counted separately. Which version of ML are you using? I used latest..